# Strange Doctrine 2 behaviour

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using a Symfony command to retrieve member details from an API afor updating in a local database.

I query my local database and then loop through each member to retrieve data and update individually. However, doctrine is not updating these member details.

I have tried to use persist and merge but none of them seems to be working which is really baffling. Below is the code I am using, hopefully an extra pair of eyes will spot what I am not:

```
$members = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->findByNot(array('pin' => "'NULL'"),array('updated_at' => 'ASC'),4,0);
    foreach($members as $member)
    {          
        $details = json_decode($api_url->apiConnect(array('login' => $member->getId(), 'password' => $member->getPassword())), true);

        $member->setFirstName($details['firstName']);
        $member->setLastName($details['lastName']);
        $member->setCard($details['card']);
        //$em->merge($member); 
        $em->persist($member);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

When I check the mysql query log, none of the update queries are run.

Comment: One little suggestion, it s always better to do the flushing after the for loop.

Comment: I do that, just that I was now trying to troubleshoot by moving things everywhere out of desparation

Comment: Did you check to see if you are even getting results back from the repository call?

Comment: Yes, I am getting four results as specified but none of those get updated with the subsequent api call information

Comment: Can you please share the definition of your 'Member'?

Comment: Did you get any `$members` at all from your query?

Comment: Is findByNot repository method you created yourself? Because I didn't heard about it and didn't found in documentation. If created by you, can you show the method content? Also another little tip, you don't need to use persist when updating entities.

Comment: I assume that you have verified that $details has different info than what is in $member?  You won't get any update queries if no data has actually changed.

Comment: The data from $details definitely changes because I am updating card numbers from null to the values from API.